# Instance variable returning None when value is present in Binary search tree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm learning my data structures thoroughly again and I've got to implementing the Binary search Tree. I have a Node class with relevant fields and a Tree class which implements the tree. I have two methods - `insert` and `get` insert works as expected but the `get` method returns None when accessing the value of any node other than the root.

Walking through the code using pycharm's debugger shows me that the particular node is reached, but the value returned in still None.

This is the Node class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
```

And here is the entire BinarySearchTree class

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, key, value):
        self.size += 1
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(key, value)
        else:
            self.insert_with_node(self.root, key, value)


    def insert_with_node(self, node, key, value):
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            if node.key > key:
                node.left = Node(key, value)
            else:
                node.right = Node(key, value)
        else:
            if node.key > key:
                if node.left is not None:
                    self.insert_with_node(node.left, key, value)
                else:
                    node.left = Node(key, value)
            else:
                if node.right is not None:
                    self.insert_with_node(node.right, key, value)
                else:
                    node.right = Node(key, value)

    def get(self, key):
        if self.root.key == key:
            return self.root.value
        else:
            return self.get_with_node(self.root, key)


    def get_with_node(self, node, key):
        if node.key > key:
            if node.left.key == key:
                return node.left.value
            else:
                self.get_with_node(node.left, key)
        else:
            if node.right.key == key:
                return node.right.value
            else:
                self.get_with_node(node.right, key)
```

EDIT: Adding testing code and console output:

```
def main():
    t = BinarySearchTree()
    t.insert(1, "g")
    t.insert(5, "qa")
    t.insert(3, "ac")
    t.insert(6, "cva")
    t.insert(12, "as")
    t.printTree(t.root)
    print(t.get(3))
```

Output :

```
C:\Python34\python.exe   C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/DSandA/BinarySearchTree.py
1 : g
3 : ac
5 : qa
6 : cva
12 : as
None
```

Comment: The code you provide had shown only the retrieving object, not creating one. so we don't know the current value of the node and where is the mistaken one.

Comment: @Chetchaiyan Just edited the question, I added the entire BST class.

Comment: I see no mistake from your code yet. If you said you can iterate to the correct node with correct 'key', I see no point you get wrong or missing 'value' since you have only 1 place to assign 'key' and 'value' together. I recommend you to check 'value' before insert to tree.

Comment: @Chetchaiyan Do you want me to edit in the testing code that I wrote to test the structure and the console output ?

Comment: @Chetchaiyan sorry for the late reply, power went out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_with_node(self, node, key):
    if node.key > key:
        if node.left.key == key:
            return node.left.value
        else:
            self.get_with_node(node.left, key)
    else:
        if node.right.key == key:
            return node.right.value
        else:
            self.get_with_node(node.right, key)
```

When a function recursively calls itself, you still need to use the `return` statement if you want anything to be returned.

```
def get_with_node(self, node, key):
    if node.key > key:
        if node.left.key == key:
            return node.left.value
        else:
            return self.get_with_node(node.left, key)
    else:
        if node.right.key == key:
            return node.right.value
        else:
            return self.get_with_node(node.right, key)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and it worked. As an aside, is there any reading material I can go through to get a better understanding of recursion ?

Comment: None that I am familiar with, sorry.